# the dual space of $C([0,1])$

Tags: functional-analysis

I'm studying Conway's Functional Analysis by myself. the following question is one of this book's Exercise.

If $n\geq 1$ , does there exist a measure $\mu$ on $[0,1]$ such that $\int pd\mu =p(0)$ for every polynomial $p$ of degree at most n? does there exist a measure $\mu$ on $[0,1]$ such that $\int pd\mu =p(0)$ for every polynomial $p$?

For this I Define $\phi:P\to \Bbb{C}$ such that $\phi(p)=p(0)$ . put $p^{(n)}=n-(n-1)x~~$  then $||p^{(n)}||=1~~$ and also $||\phi||\geq \sup_{p^{(n)}}||\phi(p)||=\sup_{p^{(n)}}|p(0)|= \sup n$ which show that $\phi$ is unbounded. so there is not any measure $\mu$ on $[0,1]$ such that $\int pd\mu =p(0)$.

But I'm not sure about my answer. I think that it's not correct. Please help me.

Comment: I'm confused. Isn't the counting measure on $\{0\}$ an easy example of this?

Comment: I'm confused too. The notation "$p^{(n)}$" usually means "$n^{\text{th}}$ derivative of $p$", doesn't it? And yes, [Dirac measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_measure) at $0$ seems like it should do the trick.

Comment: Dear kahen, I agree with you. The notation $"p(n)" $ usually means $"nth$ derivative of p" but I want to show that my polynomial is depend on n. and also about dirac measure you are right, while I think that my proof of $||\phi||$ is correct.

Comment: I don't quite understand your argument. Why do you have $||p^{(n)}||=1$?

Comment: The map $\phi$ is bounded with respect to the sup norm on $P$.